# How can I change the license key on Windows-8

Tags: windows-8, license

I have Windows-8 running. I set it up at home using my own license key. However now I need to change the license key to use it at work.

In the past I've managed to do this by editing the OOBETimer file in the windows registry to deactivate Windows and then I could re-activate it with the new key. I can't do this on Windows-8.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Launch A command prompt as Administrator and enter you key in this command

> slmgr.vbs -ipk YOUR-ACTIVATION-KEY-HERE

You will get a confirmation for the product key that you have entered.

Then, run the following script to activate the product key

> slmgr.vbs -ato

Finally you will get a confirmation on product activated successfully.

[image]

For using GUI, use

> slui 3

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to do this.

### Via GUI

1. <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run dialog, run `slui.exe 3`.
2. Type your 25-digit product key, and click/tap on Activate.

   [image: Activation]
3. Then it will try activate, and hopefully, it will be successful.

Source: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8855-product-key-number-change-windows-8-a.html

---

### Via command prompt

You could try [this](http://tweaks.com/windows/39026/change-windows-product-key-after-install/). This is also mentioned on a [blog](http://edmundlim6.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/how-to-edit-or-change-windows-8-product-key/).

1. In command prompt as Administrator (replace `SSSSS-TTTTT-UUUUU-VVVVV-WWWWW` with your key)

   ```
    slmgr.vbs /ipk SSSSS-TTTTT-UUUUU-VVVVV-WWWWW
   ```
2. Then activate Windows.

   ```
    slmgr.vbs –ato
   ```

You’ll see a pop up message once successfully activated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another method to do this but is probably a bit harder but should be documented.

Note: This was done using my Enterprise evaluation version, so other versions may have slightly different screen variations

First add the "Computer" icon to the desktop by right clicking on the desktop and select personalize, then click "change desktop icons" on the left side of the window that opens, then select Computer as one of the desktop icons, click ok.

Right click on the Computer desktop icon and select properties, a window opens, then click "View details in Windows activation" at the bottom.

(or go to Control Panel (icon view) and click System icon then view details)

[image]

You can enter a new key here.

.

[image]